# Mono compiler // Terminal emulator issue

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, f#, mono, archlinux

I get this error when I try to compile csharp or fsharp files. This happens when using gnome terminal or jetbrain rider.

It works fine in tty or termials like xterm and urxvt. 
Also I am able to compile c, c++ and go code.

Btw, I am using Arch/Antergos and got this issue yesterday.

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Console' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ConsoleDriver' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Magic number is wrong: 542
>     at System.TermInfoReader.ReadHeader (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32& position) [0x00028] in :0 
>     at System.TermInfoReader..ctor (System.String term, System.String filename) [0x0005f] in :0 
>     at System.TermInfoDriver..ctor (System.String term) [0x00055] in :0 
>     at System.ConsoleDriver.CreateTermInfoDriver (System.String term) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.ConsoleDriver..cctor () [0x0004d] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Console.SetupStreams (System.Text.Encoding inputEncoding, System.Text.Encoding outputEncoding) [0x00007] in :0 
>     at System.Console..cctor () [0x0008e] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in <2b1e99ce45b54209bdcdab138d9758ae>:0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Console' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.ConsoleDriver' threw an exception. ---> System.Exception: Magic number is wrong: 542
>     at System.TermInfoReader.ReadHeader (System.Byte[] buffer, System.Int32& position) [0x00028] in :0 
>     at System.TermInfoReader..ctor (System.String term, System.String filename) [0x0005f] in :0 
>     at System.TermInfoDriver..ctor (System.String term) [0x00055] in :0 
>     at System.ConsoleDriver.CreateTermInfoDriver (System.String term) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.ConsoleDriver..cctor () [0x0004d] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Console.SetupStreams (System.Text.Encoding inputEncoding, System.Text.Encoding outputEncoding) [0x00007] in :0 
>     at System.Console..cctor () [0x0008e] in :0 
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at Mono.CSharp.Driver.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00019] in <2b1e99ce45b54209bdcdab138d9758ae>:0

Comment: This isnt really an SO question - but more for the software developers

Comment: [This file][1] is the one with the code which causes the problem, you can download mono, modify it and recompile.
[1]: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System/TermInfoReader.cs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mono Bug : Magic number is wrong: 542](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242075/mono-bug-magic-number-is-wrong-542)